# How to use a callback function with readAsDataURL()

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, filereader

I have read this https://codeburst.io/javascript-what-the-heck-is-a-callback-aba4da2deced and many examples on here of how to use callback functions, but when I try to replicate what I see in the examples, I am not able to get it right.

I am trying to upload a pdf to an input, convert the uploaded data to a binary string, and then use the string in some way.

The problem is I can't get the "use the string" part to wait for the "convert to binary string" part.

Here is my jsfiddle, with an example of the problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/97e01nmv/2/

```
<span>upload pdf here </span><input id="doc_upload" type = "file">

<br><br>

<button id="binary_string_btn">
Get Binary String
</button>

<br><br>

<button id="use_binary_string" style="display: none;">
Do something with the binary string
</button>

<script>

$("#binary_string_btn").click(function() {
  getBase64(document.getElementById("doc_upload").files[0], handleResult);
});

function getBase64(file, callback) {
   var reader = new FileReader();
   var binary_string = reader.readAsDataURL(file);
   callback(binary_string); 
};

function handleResult(binary_string) {
    console.log(binary_string);
    $("#use_binary_string").show();
};

</script>
```

**This is how I expect it to work:**

1) user uploads pdf

2) user clicks get binary string

3) convert function makes the conversion, and calls handleResult once finished

4) handleResult uses the binary string

**What actually happens:**

1) user uploads pdf

2) user clicks get binary string

3) convert function calls handleResult immediately before finishing the conversion

4) handleResult tries to use the binary string

Answer (score 3):

Javascript is asynchronous, so your callback will be triggered before the file has been read.

You need to trigger the callback in an event from the FileReader. Take a look at the docs for a good example - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/onload

Something like this should do it -

```
function getBase64(file, callback) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event) {
        callback(event.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
 }
```